# i keep getting a reference error that user_key is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
  if(Meteor.isClient)
    {
        userKey = localStorage.getItem("user_key");
        if(!userKey){
            userKey = Meteor.uuid();
            localStorage.setItem("user_key", userKey);
        }

        getCart = function(next){
            Meteor.call("getCart", next);
        };

        addToCart = function (id, callback) {
            Meteor.call('addToCart',userKey, id, callback);
        };
        removeFromCart = function (id, callback) {
            Meteor.call('removeFromCart',userKey, id, callback);
        };
        updateCart = function (id, quantity, callback) {
            Meteor.call('updateCart', userKey, id, quantity, callback);
        };
    }

    if(Meteor.isServer) {
        Meteor.methods({

            "getCart": function (userKey) {
                check(userKey, String);
                return Carts.getCart(userKey);
            },
            "addToCart": function (userKey, id) {
                check(userKey, String);
                check(id, String);
                var cart = Meteor.call("getCart", userKey);

                //get the item in the cart
                var found = _.find(cart.items, function (item) {
                    return item._id === id;
                });

                if (found)
                {
                    found.quantity++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //add the item
                    var product = Products.findOne({_id: id});
                    var item = {
                        id: product._id,
                        name: product.productName,
                        price: product.price,
                        shop: product.shop,
                        image: product.productImg,
                        discount: 0,
                        added_at: new Date(),
                        quantity: 1
                    };
                    cart.items.push(item);

                }
                cart.notes.push({
                    note: id + " added to cart",
                    created_at: new Date()
                });
                //save it
                Meteor.call("saveCart", cart);
                return cart;
            },
            "updateCart": function (userKey, id, quantity)
            {
                check(userKey, String);
                check(id, String);
                check(quantity, Match.Where(function (quantity)
                {
                    check(quantity, Number);
                    return quantity >= 0;
                }));
                var cart = Meteor.call("getCart", userKey);
                //only update the quantity here
                _.each(cart.items, function (item)
                {
                    if (item._id === id)
                    {
                        item.quantity = quantity;
                        return Meteor.call("saveCart", cart);
                    }
                });
            },
            "removeFromCart": function (userKey, id)
            {
                check(userKey, String);
                check(id, String);
                var cart = Meteor.call("getCart", userKey);
                //get the item in the cart

                var found = _.find(cart.items, function (item)
                {
                    return item._id === id;
                });

                if (found)
                {
                    var foundIndex = cart.items.indexOf(found);
                    cart.items.splice(foundIndex, 1);
                    cart.notes.push({
                        note: id + " removed from cart",
                        created_at: new Date()
                    });
                    Meteor.call("saveCart", cart);
                }

                return cart;
            },
            "saveCart": function (cart) {
                check(cart, Match.ObjectIncluding({
                    userKey: String,
                    items: [Match.ObjectIncluding({
                        id: String
                    })]
                }));

                var products = Products.find({
                    _id: {$in: _.pluck(cart.items, '_id')}
                }).fetch();

                var skuMap = _.object(_.pluck(products, '_id'), products);

                cart.updated_at = new Date();
                cart.total = 0;
                var counter = 0;
                _.each(cart.items, function (item)
                {
                    item.price = skuMap[item._id].price;
                    item.quantity = Math.max(0, item.quantity);
                    // TODO: Don't trust discount from client
                    item.lineTotal = (item.price - item.discount) * item.quantity;
                    cart.total += item.lineTotal;
                    counter++;
                });
                cart.itemCount = counter;
                Carts.update({userKey: cart.userKey}, cart, {upsert: true});
                return cart;
            },
            "emptyCart": function (userKey)
            {
                check(userKey, String);
                Carts.remove({userKey: userKey});
            }
        })
    }
```

The code above is for a simple cart system. Gets the users uuid, sets that as the user_key and does normal add to cart, get cart and update cart operations. I have checked my browser and i know the userkey is being set in localStorage, but when i call addToCart method i keep getting the following error in the image below.

[image]
This is my Carts.getCart function below.

```
Carts.getCart = function()
{
    var cart = Carts.findOne({userKey : userKey});

    if(!cart){
        cart = {
            userKey : userKey,
            email : null,
            name :null,
            ip : null,
            created_at : new Date(),
            items : [],
            notes : [{
                note : "Cart created",
                created_at : new Date()
            }],
            status : "open",
            itemCount : 0,
            total : 0
        };
    }
    return cart;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need to add var before userKey :

```
var userKey = localStorage.getItem("user_key");
```

Also try to save in session and get the value :

```
localStorage.setItem("user_key", userKey);
Session.set("user_key", localStorage.getItem(userKey));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i forgot to pass in userkey to the getCart function